# Remove special chars from generics output in ASP.NET Web API GET method

Tags: c#, generics, asp.net-web-api

I want to remove special chars from the Web API response in `GET` action method. The method `Regex.Replace()` is not working in this case as it accepts only strings.

Is there any way to remove special chars from a generic output?

```
    [Route("api/LookUp/GetEmpresult/{EmpId}")]
    [HttpGet]       
    public IEnumerable<EMPLookup> GetEmpresult(string EmpId)
    {
        EMPDataAccess empdb = new EMPDataAccess();

        return empdb.GetEmp(EmpId);          
    }
```

Comment: What else would you expect a text manipulation library to work on, if not strings? Assuming you're complaining about the strings in the JSON, you should process the DTOs before they get returned and converted to JSON. A better question overall here is: why do you have special characters in your database that you don't want? Why not validate the data going in and prevent them from being added in the first place?

Comment: apply middleware that will use reflection to get each property of response type and apply Regex.Replace() in case of string

Comment: what is the result that you get and what do you want to remove?